# Constructor and destructor order on static allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I wrote this simple code, I expected a different result.

```
struct Test {
  int value_;
  Test(): value_(0) {
    std::cout << "Constructor: "<< value_ << "\n";
  }

  Test(int value): value_(value) {
    std::cout << "Constructor: "<< value_ << "\n";
  }

  ~Test() {
    std::cout << "Destructor: "<< value_ << "\n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Test t;
  t = Test(10);
  t = Test(15);
  t = Test(20);
  t = Test(25);
}
```

And the result:

```
Constructor: 0
Constructor: 10
Destructor: 10
Constructor: 15
Destructor: 15
Constructor: 20
Destructor: 20
Constructor: 25
Destructor: 25
Destructor: 25
```

I was surprised because it did not expect the last line would be repeated. Why `Destructor: 0` was not called?

Comment: When printing constructors and destructors you need to make sure you decorate the copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first "Destructor: 25" is from the destruction of the temporary object created by `Test(25)`; the second is from the destruction of `t` into which that has been copied.

Other than that last "Destructor:" line and the first "Constructor:", all the output is from the creation and destruction of those temporary objects. There is no "Destructor: 0" because you never make a temporary object with value 0, and by the time `t` is destroyed its value is no longer 0.

Comment: the line `Test t;` makes a temporary object with value 0,

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum No it does not.  `t` is not a temporary.

Comment: Parsed it funny, I did not read `temporary object` as a phrase, just thought `t` wont last forever.

Answer (score 1):

The first of those lines corresponds to the destruction of the temporary object.

The second of those lines corresponds to the destruction of `t`.

When `t` is destructed, its `value_` is `25` since you used

```
t = Test(25);
```

as the last line in `main`.